# mongoDB query to get all users that are not followed by a user

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I'm new to mongoDB and I'm facing some difficulty in writing a query .

for a given user I need to find which user he is yet to follow .

```
{
  _id:1,
  username:"user1",
  follows:[2,3]
},
{
  _id:2,
  username:"user2",
  follows:[3]
},
{
  _id:3,
  username:"user3",
  follows:[1]
},
{
  _id:4,
  username:"user4",
  follows:[2,1]
},
{
  _id:5,
  username:"user5",
  follows:[3]
}
```

note that the `follows` field contain `_id` of users that a particular our user is following.
I need to write a query that gives me a list of all users that a user is not following.
like for user 1 its not following user 4, and user 5

so for user1 my output would be :-

```
{
  _id:4,
  username:"user4",
  follows:[2,1]
},
{
  _id:5,
  username:"user5",
  follows:[3]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must retrieve the `follows` field of the given user and use `$nin` like this:

```
const userId = 1;

const { follows } = await User.findById(userId);
follows.push(userId); // also exclude user 1

const users_list = await User.find({ _id: { $nin: follows } });
```

Comment: even though its also showing the current user also in the list of users result , but that's okay I will filter that out .. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$follows",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false // optional
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                user_ids: {
                    $addToSet: '$_id'
                },
                follows: {
                    $addToSet: '$follows'
                },
                doc: {
                    $push: '$$ROOT'
                }


            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                doc: 1,
                notfollowed: {
                    $setDifference: ["$user_ids", "$follows"]
                }
            }
        },

    ]



);
```